# playing a .caf file: works fine in simulator but not in iPhone

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, caf

I'm building a voice recorder. Recoding and playing works fine on simulator. But on iphone it doesn't work. (I followed the exact steps as mentioned in [iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW2))

```
    printf("%s(player)\n",[[self.soundFileURL absoluteString] UTF8String]);

    AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
    [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: self.soundFileURL error: nil];

    if([self.soundFileURL isFileURL]){
        printf("isFileURL\n");
    }

    self.player = newPlayer;
    [newPlayer release];

    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player setDelegate: self];
    //recorderLabel.text=@"Playing..";
    [player play];
    printf("playing..\n");
```

The debugger out put is 
    file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/9A607A45-974B-4E9F-9839-FD21B3BC9DD8/Documents/1251828741.caf(player)
    isFileURL
    playing..

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone OS on-device does not have the same audio codecs available to it that the iPhone OS in-simulator does. In my projects I have had problems playing back `.caf` files encoded one way but not another... a bit of trial and error will help here (I ended up using 16BLE PCM).

I would try altering the recorded audio file's encoding in an attempt to find an audio codec supported by the device.

Comment: Huh?  If you run afconvert -hf, "16BLE" isn't even listed as a format.  Is this another name for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure sound isn't turned off on the iPhone.

Add the following to your delegate (self):

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)playedPlayer successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"Done playing %@", flag ? @"with success" : @"with failure" );
}

- (void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:(AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error while decoding: %@", [error localizedDescription] );
}
```

This might give you some clues.

Answer (score 0):

.caf file for iPhone need to be encoded as a mono channel and not with a stereo channel then only it will work with iPhone.