# SimpleAudioEngine, playing .caf files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [playing a .caf file: works fine in simulator but not in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363972/playing-a-caf-file-works-fine-in-simulator-but-not-in-iphone)

I'm trying to use SimpleAudioEngine to play background music in an iPhone app I'm working on. I play the background music using the following code:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadBackgroundMusic: @"MenuTheme.mp3"];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic: @"MenuTheme.mp3" loop: YES];
```

This works fine.

However, when I convert MenuTheme.mp3 to MenuTheme.caf using terminal with the following line:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16 "MenuTheme.mp3" "MenuTheme.caf"
```

and I use SimpleAudioEngine again to play the .caf file, it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this? The .caf file does play when I click it. In terminal, when I write:

```
afinfo "MenuTheme.caf"
```

It tells me the data format is 2 ch, 44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x0000000C) 16-bit little-endian signed integer no channel layout.

I really don't know what's wrong, but I'm also very new to using audio on the iPhone. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

edit: afconvert misspelled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363972/playing-a-caf-file-works-fine-in-simulator-but-not-in-iphone

Comment: thanks, you'd think Apple would try to make sure both the simulator and iPhone devices would have the same codecs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is `afconvert` not `fconvert` as metioned in your question. (I believe that was a typo, right?) I don't see obvious problem on your command line. I usually use:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@22050 sound.wav
```

to convert my wave files to CAF.

Since you cannot play the CAF files by clicking it, I suggest to have a try to convert it to other formats like wave or AIFF:

```
afconvert -f AIFC -d ima4 sound.wav
```

and try to play them in Finder. If it doesn't work either, try to convert the MPEG Layer 3 file to wave first by some third-party tools such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) and try again with `afconvert`.

P.S. I usually use CAF for sound effects, and use AIFF for background music. Please refer to: [Sound on iOS: Best Practices.](http://gamua.com/blog/2010/06/sound-on-ios-best-practices/)

Comment: Thanks, explanation and link to Best Practices were very helpful. I will try using AIFF for the background music and CAF for sound effects.