# Cocos2d-iphone is unable to play my .caf files upon conversion

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, caf

I am having the same problem as this question: [SimpleAudioEngine, playing .caf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286686/simpleaudioengine-playing-caf-files) (which is closed)

The solution, however, does not work.

I have `Battle.wav`, which works just fine with

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playBackgroundMusic:@"Battle.wav"];
```

Now, I want to convert it to .caf. According to the answer in that question, I should use this terminal line:

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@22050 Battle.wav
```

The resulting file, however, does not work. When I use:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playBackgroundMusic:@"Battle.caf"];
```

Xcode displays the following message when I do that:

> AudioStreamBasicDescription:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, 'lpcm' (0x00000C2C)
>   8.24-bit little-endian signed integer, deinterleaved

I don't really know what does that mean. What I do know, however, is that the file indeed does not sound.

The question at [playing a .caf file: works fine in simulator but not in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363972/playing-a-caf-file-works-fine-in-simulator-but-not-in-iphone) doesn't help either (and the problem they have doesn't seem the same basic thing I'm having here).

Cocos2d-iphone 1.0.1, iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening and exporting the file as AIFF (.caf) using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net) (free). That should work if it is a file format problem.

One thing that may be an issue is the caf file using 2 channels. It may be as simple as SimpleAudioEngine not supporting stereo sound effects. If you want background music, use .mp3 since they can be decoded in hardware, and are generally a lot smaller.

Comment: Are .mp3 generally smaller than .caf?

Comment: Hm, it doesn't seem to be working. The file was actually stereo, but with Audacity I transformed it to mono.. still no luck. BTW I bought your book :D